# Enable/Disable ribbon button from Form

Tags: vb.net, ribbon

Hi I've Windows form with checkbox. I would like enable/disable single button attach into my ribbon. Wound somebody show me a right way?

Part of XML code Ribbon looks like this

```
<tab idMso="TabNewMailMessage">
        <group id="Kompresja2"
               label="Lab1">
          <toggleButton id="Kompresja6"
              imageMso="Smile"
              onAction="ProcedureX"
              getPressed="Wcisnieto"
              getEnabled="Czytaj_stan"
              label="Lab2"
              size="large"
          />
        </group>
      </tab>
```

Comment: Lots of ribbon controls around, none that everybody has available in their toolbox since the .NET Framework doesn't have one.  You need to be a lot more specific about the one you are using.  Use the proper tag on your question.

Comment: Why ask a question, to which no response is obtained scored a minus. Some nonsense.

Comment: More specific? ok. Ive Windows Form in my VB.Office project, with any controls. I want to push one of them to control my own Ribbon buttons, because I wish to turn on and off (enable/disable it) in the menu. Maybe someone know how to do that, another then pushing minus to this post.

Answer (score 1):

- The getEnabled callback function (in your case `Czytaj_stan`) checks to see if the button is enabled or not - returns True if the button should
  be enabled, False if not.
- The getEnabled callback function is called whenever the ribbon-control is invalidated, which is whenever the office application decides it is needed, e.g. when it has been minimized, or when you make it by calling `[IRibbonUI-object].InvalidateControl("Kompresja6")` to invalidate just that control or `[IRibbonUI-object].Invalidate()` to redraw the whole ribbon (`[IRibbonUI-object].InvalidateControlMso("ID")` invalidates a built-in control).
- The reference to the IRibbonUI-object needs to be set when the custom ribbon loads.

In order to make this work you need to:

1. Make sure you can get the reference to the IRibbonUI-object by adding an onLoad callback function in your customUI XML-tag: `<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">`.
2. Implement he `Ribbon_Load` callback function and set a reference to the `IRibbonUI`-parameter.
3. Implement the getEnabled function `Czytaj_stan` to decide when the button should be enabled or not.
4. Have your form-button first modify the conditions for enabled/disabled in `Czytaj_stan`, then call `[IRibbonUI-object].InvalidateControl("Kompresja6")` to invalidate the ribbon-button.